# Solved my problem posted to SO by changing the version of a package, but still want to know the issue with the newest version. What should I do?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

Today I posted a problem I had with [Mongoose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongoose_%28web_server%29) 6.0.0 to Stack Overflow, and now (after a few hours) I managed to make my code work by changing the Mongoose version to 5.13.8. I still want to know why the code doesn't work on 6.0.0, but I think the "partial" solution I got may help somebody in the same situation I was in.

Should I answer my own question or edit the original question with the solution?

Comment: If you find that your code works in some older version, you can freely edit that information in the question. But don't add it like "I have found solution- reverting to version x)", rather say this code is working in version x, but it is not working in version y. How can I make it work in y." or something similar. It is possible that at some point some answer will say, you can use version y.1 that fixe the issue, but that is valid answer, too and you can add that one if something like this happens.

Comment: Posting answer that only say reverting to version x solved the problem, might be seen as poor quality answer, especially if you post it yourself because it could have been incorporated into the question. Even if you found that fact afterwards.

Comment: However, if someone already posted answer that reverting to version x is the solution, then you should not edit the question because it invalidate the answer. Just don't accept that answer to signal that you are still looking for other solutions.

Comment: Never edit the original question with the solution. Post every solution even partial solutions as answer.

Comment: The very disappointing answer is likely going to be "regression". You're better off posting a bug report than a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @Gimby Since it's a difference in the major version number, the answer might be "a backwards-incompatible change was made intentionally", instead of "regression". I think asking on Stack Overflow before making a bug report is fine in this circumstance.

Comment: I'd definitely recommend searching the project's bug tracker for the issue.  Often the answer to this kind of question is along the lines of "downgrade to the previous version until a fix for <bug-tracker-issue> has been released".

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**TL;DR: Include this information in the question.**

Congratulations, you have found a work-around.

As you noted, however, a work-around is not really an answer: you still can't use the new version, and therefore can't use its new functionality.

Still, the work-around is of interest to other users, who could use it, so it should be mentioned somewhere. The possibilities are:

- The question itself.
- A comment below the question.

In this case, I'd argue for editing the question itself. The fact that your application works with the old version, but not the new one, is likely a clue as to the underlying issue, and clues belong to the question.

---

Note that in general, answering a question is likely to result in *no* additional answers being added. Would-be answerers have a tendency to scan the front-page (eye-balling, or using filters) for questions with no answer *before opening the question*.

As such, a *poor* answer can have a nefarious effect: it makes the question less likely to attract a good answer.

Comment: _"As such, a poor answer can have a nefarious effect: it makes the question less likely to attract a good answer."_ it does? Is this anecdotal?

Comment: @PasserBy: Anecdotal. Probably very much depends on the tags. My experience in a popular tag ([tag:c++]) is that there's many people jumping on the question as soon as it's asked, and the quality of answers is so-so, so the presence of non-accepted answers doesn't deter contribution (the presence of accepted answers does). On a much less popular tag ([tag:rust]), however, there are many less answerers, and in general answers are of higher quality, so the few people willing to answer tend to focus on non-answered questions.

Comment: That makes sense. From what I remember of my own habits, I tend to specifically check answers to possibly complicated questions in c++, because it was just so darn easy to get it wrong, and then proceed to answer if the existing one is bad enough.

Answer (score 21):

Answer your own question with what worked for you. It might help others. Don't accept that answer and leave a comment under the question or under that answer; saying that you still wish to know what caused the problem in the first place and that you won't be accepting your own answer.

Then, wait. If you don't get an answer after 2 or more days, try adding a bounty to your question (you don't have the reputation to do so right now though) to bring attention to it.

If you still don't get an answer then wait longer, if this issue was caused by a newer version of the package then other people will also be facing it and an answer might eventually come.

Comment: Going back to a previous version is a workaround at best. Other people may need to use features specific to the newer version and might not be able to go back. It's definitely worth waiting for other answers.

Answer (score 20):

Whether or not "it works in version 5.13.8" is an answer depends on what question you are asking.

- If your question is "how can I make my thing work?" then "downpatch to 5.13.8" is an answer (albeit usually not a good answer).
- If your question is "how can I make my thing work without downpatching?" then "you should downpatch" is explicitly rejected as an acceptable answer, but the fact it works in the older version is relevant to the question so should be included there.
- If your question is "why doesn't it work in the latest version?" then "you should downpatch" isn't even addressing the question, but the fact it works in the older version is *essential* to the question and *must* be included there.

All three of these are common types of question asked on Stack Overflow. Which one you are asking is up to you, but you should make sure your question makes it clear. If not, edit to add clarity (but ideally not in a way which invalidates existing answers, if there are any).

Comment: I slightly disagree with this.  I don't think the OP's are intentions are the key here.  I think the OP should be deciding their course of action depending on what they >actually< asked.  If someone wants to know A but actually asked B, then from the perspective of anyone other than the question asker the question is really about B, not A.  Obviously ... it depends how whether the question is coherent enough to properly distinguish A and B, and how far apart they are.

Comment: @StephenC Yes, agreed; I'm assuming a question which is not already clear enough to distinguish this, and which needs to be clarified, and I'm assuming there are no answers at the time of editing (implied but not stated by OP). In that case, the question is still in the stage where it needs to be improved in order to decide what is or isn't an answer, and it's that stage where the OP's intent matters. If the question already has a clear, unambiguous meaning (and especially if it already has valid answers according to that meaning) then the question's meaning shouldn't be changed, of course.

Comment: Your last sentence in your comment is key!

Answer (score 6):

I consider downgrading to a previous version part of the debugging process. That's rarely a solution, since you would expect either to later versions not breaking your current code or being advised how to change your code so it now do the right thing.

I wouldn't put that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the general case, you can choose either of the options. If the question is *"How do I do X with library Y? My version is Z"* then *"Downgrade to version W"* is an acceptable answer. But you can also change the question to *"How do I do X with library Y? My version is Z. It worked with version W but not Z."*

However, there is one thing you should be careful with, and that is that you should never invalidate existing answers. If someone already have posted that answer, then it's NOT ok to edit the question.

In the case where it already exists answers, but you realize that you really need to use a specific version, then you might consider asking a new question. This is also applicable when you find questions when searching for solutions to your problem. (You did search before asking? Didn't you?) I have done that a few times. A question like this is perfectly fine:

> I have problem doing X. I found this question <link> but all answers assumes that it is run on an x86 processor, but I need to run this on a Sparc.